# Outlook Rest API - 503 Service Unavailable for only one user in the domain, other users work

Tags: outlook-restapi

I am trying to help a user connect to the Outlook API.  Three of this person's colleagues, who all have the same email domain, are able to successfully connect and executed API calls, but the one user is receiving 503 Service Unavailable responses.

The user is able to successfully get an access token, and that access token can also successfully be refreshed.

Here is an example request and response from the "Outlook Dev Center - Oauth Sandbox Tool" https://oauthplay.azurewebsites.net/.

```
GET https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/me/mailfolders/sentitems/messages?$filter=sentdatetime%20ge%202017-02-13T00:00:00Z HTTP/1.1
Accept: text/*, application/xml, application/json; odata.metadata=none
User-Agent: PlayGroundAgent/1.0
Authorization: Bearer {hidden}
client-request-id: ce0330c6-56cd-4ab9-b3ab-69670b565cac
X-AnchorMailbox: {hidden}


HTTP/1.1 503 Service Unavailable
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
request-id: c81e91cc-705d-4abe-a6e5-5bafbdd62b87
X-CalculatedFETarget: MWHPR01CU001.internal.outlook.com
X-BackEndHttpStatus: 503, 503
X-FEProxyInfo: MWHPR01CA0012.PROD.EXCHANGELABS.COM
X-CalculatedBETarget: MWHPR16MB1583.namprd16.prod.outlook.com
OData-Version: 4.0
X-DiagInfo: MWHPR16MB1583
X-BEServer: MWHPR16MB1583
X-FEServer: MWHPR01CA0012, MWHPR15CA0056
Cache-Control: private
Date: Mon, 13 Feb 2017 20:11:39 GMT
Set-Cookie: exchangecookie={hidden}; expires=Tue, 13-Feb-2018 20:11:40 GMT; path=/; HttpOnly
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET

{
    "error": {
        "code": "ErrorServiceUnavailable",
        "message": "Active Directory operation did not succeed. Try again later."
    }
}
```

My understanding is that this user was once on Exchange and has been migrated to Office 365 in recent years.  The three users who are able to connect were not originally on Exchange, they all had their accounts created, net new, on Office 365.  My assumption is that something in the migration process from Exchange to Office 365 is causing the 503 Service Unavailable responses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue can occur when a user has the same SMTP address for both a consumer and a business account.  The simplest solution may be to just select the correct account when authorizing the application that will be using the Outlook API.

The user can also change the alias for the consumer account as described in this article: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/-Something-went-wrong-page-with-error-ADDriverStoreAccessNonLocalException-4133f321-4af1-4f7d-98af-7756f5892bb7?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US.